# Split HTML document into words and spans using PHP

Tags: php, xpath

Using PHP I want to split an HTML document into its individual words, but keeping certain `<span>`s together. This is as close as I've got so far, with a minimal example of HTML (that would be larger and more complex in reality):

```php
$html = '<html><body>

<h1>My header</h1>

<p>A test <b>paragraph</b> with <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">Bob Ferris</span> a person.</p>

</body></html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query('.//span[@itemtype]|.//text()[normalize-space()]') as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeType . " " . $node->nodeValue . "<br>";
}
```

This outputs:

> 3 My header
>   3 A test
>   3 paragraph
>   3 with
>   1 Bob Ferris
>   3 Bob Ferris
>   3 a person.

(`nodeType` 3 is a text node, 1 is an element)

I also need to:

- Split text nodes into individual words and strip punctuation (easily done at this stage, but could it be done in the xpath query?)
- Only capture the "Bob Ferris" element, and not the "Bob Ferris" text node.
- I will need to access the attributes of these `<span>`s too, with `$node->getAttribute()`

Comment: I guess that instead of `.//text()` I want to say "all text nodes that aren't within `span[@itemtype]`"...?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do it:

```php
// 1: Match all <span>s with an itemtype attribute.
// 2: OR
// 3: Match text strings that are not in one of those spans (and get rid of some spaces).
foreach($xpath->query('.//span[@itemtype]|.//text()[not(parent::span[@itemtype])][normalize-space()]') as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeType == 1) {
        // A span.
        echo $node->nodeValue . "<br>";
    } else {
        // A text node - split into words and trim trailing periods.
        $words = explode(" ", trim($node->nodeValue));
        foreach($words as $word) {
            echo rtrim($word, ".") . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, a one liner with XPath 2.0 :

```
tokenize(replace(replace(concat(string-join((//text()[not(parent::span)][normalize-space()])[position()<last()]|//span[@itemtype],","),replace((//text()[not(parent::span)][normalize-space()])[last()],"\W$","")),"\W+",","),replace(//span[@itemtype]/text(),"\W+",","),//span[@itemtype]/text()),",+")
```

Output :

[image: XPath2]